# Recover Windows Server 2003 Backup via Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, backup, windows-server-2003, windows-backup, tape

Can Windows 8 be used to recover a backup made with the Windows Server 2003 `Backup` application?  I have a tape backup that was created on an old Windows Server 2003 server that is no longer functional.  I will be able to put this tape drive into another system with Windows 8, but would like to verify that I will be able to use some application in Windows 8 that will read the old Windows Server 2003 data properly for retrieval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might depend on the software that was used to create it.  If it was, in fact, Microsoft Backup that was used, then you should be able to recover with Windows 8 (assuming you have tape drive drivers for Windows 8).  Through Windows 8, the Backup utility has changed, but it is backward compatible.

Good luck.

Comment: That is what I was needing to know, eg is the Windows 8 backup utility capable of reading the MS backup data files from Windows 2003.  Thanks.